# Datetime picker is not working properly calendar is not showing any thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

Date and time picker is not working I have tried to use conflict because of I am using a full calendar with this and gull admin theme but noting have work. how would I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more info (sample code, libraries, error in console, bla bla)

Comment: This code i am using and jquert date picker plugin using from 

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

  `$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#demo').datetimepicker(); 
    });
</script>`
jquery.datetimepicker.css
jquery.datetimepicker.js

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with adding $.noConflict();